# Add to end of line that contains a specific word and starts with x

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to add some custom text to the end of all lines in my document opened in Notepad++ that start with `10` and contain a specific word (for example "frog").

So far, I managed to solve the first part.

> *Search:* `^(10)$`
>
> *Replace:* `\1;Batteries`   (to add `;Batteries` to the end of the line)

What I need now is to edit this regex pattern to recognize only those lines that also contain a specific word.

For example:

> *Before*: **10**50;There is this **frog** in the lake
>
> *After*: 1050;There is this frog in the lake;Batteries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should allow any characters between the number and the end of line:

`^10.*frog.*`

And replacement will be `$0;Batteries`. You do not even need a `$` anchor as `.*` matches till the end of a line since `.` matches any character but a line break char.

**NOTE**: There is no need to wrap the whole pattern with capturing parentheses, the `$0` placeholder refers to the whole match value.

*More details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `10` - a literal `10` text
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `frog` - a literal string
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

Comment: I have one additional question. What if i want to search for word "frog" only between first and second semicolon delimiter. For example `1050 dont search here;search for frog here;also not look here;not here`

Comment: That is a bit complicated, but possible: `^10([^;]*;[^;]*frog[^;]*;.*)$` (or `^10([^;]*;[^;]*\bfrog\b[^;]*;.*)$` if you search for a whole word `frog`). We search for `10` at the beginning, then anything but `;`, then the 1st delimiter `;`, then any number of non-`;` and our word, then again anything but `;`, the 2nd delimiter, and then any number of any symbols until the end of line.

Comment: Complicated indeed. :) Thank you for the deep explanation of what certain part of this regex does.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the regex to match your wanted lines:

```
(^(10).*?(frog).*)
```

the .*? is a lazy quantifier to get the minimum until frog

and replace by :

```
$1;Battery
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

try this 
find with: `(^(10).*(frog).*)`
replace with: `$1;Battery`

Answer (score 1):

Use `^(10.*frog.*)$` as regex. Replace it with something like `$1;Batteries`